# Composite unique identifiers and barred relationship

Tags: oracle, data-modeling, erd

I'm stuck on this problem: Resolve M:M relationships between FACULTY and the COURSE. Identify the composite unique identifiers that result from a barred relationship.

**Faculty table**

```
# Faculty ID                                        
* Faculty Name
* Faculty Email
```

**Course table**

```
# Course ID
* Course Name
* Session ID
* Department ID
```

Comment: note that the faculty and the course are the titles and not the ones in bold print

Answer (score 0):

An intersection table has the keys of the two tables it joins. So

**Faculty-Course table**

```
# Faculty ID   
# Course ID
```

In addition to the compound primary key, Faculty ID should be a foreign on FACULTY and Course ID should be a foreign on COURSE.

---

Incidentally, I see you tagged your question `[erd]`. It is not usual to resolve M:M in the Logical Data Model. It's normally a task we undertake when doing the Physical Data Model.